# Show active users using timestamp

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to show active users in the system.

Then every 5 minutes I created a function that updates the database with the current date.

In the end I have to delete the records where the date is less than the current date + 10 minutes

```
DELETE FROM `user_online` WHERE data < (NOW() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)

<?php
  @session_start();
  $session = session_id();
  $time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

  $tbl_name = "user_online"; // Table name

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE session='$session'");

  $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

  if($count == 0){

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tbl_name(session, data) VALUES ('$session', '$time')");

  }else { 

    mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET data='$time' WHERE session = '$session'");

  }

// if over 10 minute, delete session

$result4 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE data < (NOW() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)");
// Open multiple browser page for result
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  function update(){
    <?php include('online.php'); ?>
  }
  setInterval("update()",10000);
</script>
```

The script is deleting all records, what's wrong?

Comment: `(NOW() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)` is 10 minutes in the future. A timestamp that gets set to the current time can never get that value, can it?

Answer (score 3):

Wrong sign

```
DELETE FROM `user_online` WHERE data < (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

`NOW() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE` is in ten minutes from now, and all your records are older than that.

Comment: the problem now is not to insert more records.
I looked it seems that now is deleting all records

Comment: @user but it is deleting all the records because you are telling it to delete all records except for those that have a timestamp 10 minutes in the future. That doesn't make sense, does it?

Answer (score 0):

You are putting a record into the database, then telling it: "delete everything LESS THAN 10 minutes from now"... But what you just input fits into that criteria. If I put in a record at 12:20, then it is <12:30 and will get deleted.